# Suddenly none of my linked tables work in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, indexing, text, linked-tables

I have a large MS Access application that uses linked tables to a SQL Server back end. The Access database links to SQL Server via ODBC.

Suddenly, none of my linked tables work, if there is a unique index anywhere in the SQL table containing a text field.  This setup has worked for almost 20 years then suddenly, I am seeing #Deleted in every column and row in any linked table.

I am using the 64 bit standard version of Microsoft SQL Server on AWS.  The Access version is the latest version of Microsoft Office 365.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just had this issue myself - but I still had a problem with the ODBC 17 driver after converting. I had to change my `nvarchar(MAX)` fields to a defined length like `nvarchar(1024)` - Also still experiencing some issues with tables/queries using fields defined as `date` not `datetime`

Comment: I rolled back the latest 365 update and all is well again.

Comment: Good plan - sounds like any keys with nvarchar fields had to have the fields changed to varchar (without rollback)

Comment: The MS Team is, apparently, aware of this and a new update is on the way - may have already arrives, depending upon your update 365 channel.  Build 2206 is supposed to resolve the #Deleted issue.